# Need a heap allocated pointer, but I'm given a stack allocated pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, memory-management

I would like to have a class contain a `std::unique_ptr` initialized by the constructor then used elsewhere in the class.

So I've got a class that contains a `std::unique_ptr` like this:

```
class ObjectA
{
public:
    ObjectA();
    ~ObjectA();
    void SomeFunction();

private:
    std::unique_ptr<ObjectB> myPointer;
}
```

Then in the class's source file `myPointer` is setup in the constructor and used in `SomeFunction()`.

```
ObjectA::ObjectA()
{
    ObjectC objectC;
    myPointer = std::move(std::unique_ptr<ObjectB>(objectC.getPointer())); //setup pointer
}

ObjectA::~ObjectA() {}

void ObjectA::SomeFunction()
{
    //use myPointer here
}
```

The problem though, is that I can't use `myPointer` in `SomeFunction()`, and here's why.

Obviously `myPointer` must be allocated on the heap to assure it doesn't get destroyed when the constructor is done executing. Assume that `ObjectC` and consequentially it's functions are from an external library. When I call `ObjectC::getPointer()` the pointer that's return is probably allocated on the stack apposed to the heap. Now I assume this is the case because right after the constructor has finished executing I get an error.

Basically I'm relying on a function to give me a pointer with wich I can then use elsewhere. However, the function allocates the object on the stack instead of the heap.

Is there some special way to solve this problem, maybe with a double pointer? Or will I just have to call `ObjectC::getPointer()` every time I want to use the pointer inside each execution block? If I had lots of functions inside `ObjectA` which rely on `myPointer` then calling `ObjectC::getPointer()` per function would be redundant, but I don't know if there is a better way to fix this, and I feel like a function (`ObjectC::getPointer()`) shouldn't force me into that redundancy.

Comment: Are you sure `objectC` doesn't control the lifetime of the pointed to object? It seems like that is the case. You probably should have `ObjectC objectC` as a member of your class. Also, `ObjectC objectC();` should be `ObjectC objectC;` (the former is a function declaration).

Comment: Without knowing how ObjectB and ObjectC are defined it's impossible to say for sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `ObjectC::getPointer()`, you don't just get "a" pointer. The function must specify what operations are valid on the pointer, and in particular how it should be disposed.

Usually, that would be `delete`, but it could also be e.g. `fclose`. You'll have to read the documentation. If the lifetime of the returned pointer matches that lifetime of `objectC`, then the lifetime of `objectC` should match `myPointer`. So it probably should be a member, and that in turn means that `myPointer` might be redundant. You could just substitute `private: ObjectB& getB() { return *myObjectC.GetPointer(); }`